# how to read UrlPrefixes from appsettings in program.cs - asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpsys

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("how to get url from appsettings");
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        //host as window service
        .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

appsettings config,

```
"HttpSysOptions": {
    "UrlPrefix": "http://localhost:8099/"
}
```

Looks like I can use `hostingContext.Configuration`, but it won't available within `UseHttpSys`, how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IWebHostBuilder.UseHttpSys(Action)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderhttpsysextensions.usehttpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1) consists of two parts: Registering the required services, and configuring the [`HttpSysOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.httpsysoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can split this up by registering only the required services and configuring the options yourself. And when you do that, you can access the hosting context:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseHttpSys();
        webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add(context.Configuration["HttpSysOptions:UrlPrefix"]);
            });
        });

        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

    string urlPrefix = configuration.GetSection("HttpSysOptions")["UrlPrefix"];
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add(urlPrefix);
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        //host as window service
        .UseWindowsService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating yet another configuration that you need to set up (and keep in sync if you have different sources, like environment-specific configurations) is really not needed with the generic host.

Comment: @poke Oh cool, I didn't know about `webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services)`. Glad I learned something on a Sunday ;)

Comment: You just finaly saved me from hours of searching :) thank you